# How can I fix "HEAD detached at origin/development" when I have 2 remotes

Tags: git, github

I have a repo that has another remote *<remote_2>* besides origin. When I execute a command `git checkout development`, it checks out to *<remote_2>/development* branch. Now, I want to checkout to *origin/development*. When I execute a command `git checkout origin/development` it says:

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

And when I do `git status` it says: HEAD detached at origin/development.

I'm not that good into git, but how can I checkout to *origin/development*, because I want to push commits on origin remote, and only sometimes to <remote_2>.

When I do `git branch -a` I have this:

```
* development
  main
  remotes/remote_2/development
  remotes/remote_2/main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/development
  remotes/origin/main
```

Comment: If `development` branch did _not_ exist locally and there are two remote branches called `development`, if you only did `git checkout development`, git would _refuse_ to create a local branch from either of them, you would have to specify which branch you would like to create it from. That probably means that you already had a local `development` branch that was created from `remote_2/development`... and when you checkout `development` you are **not** checking out `remote_2/development`. Then, you _can't_ have a single local branch that is somehow tracking both remote branches of the same name

Comment: Anyway.... you can checkout `development` (local one) and then push to either of the two remotes: `git push remote_1 development` or `git push remote_2 development`

Comment: And... most importantly **do not believe a single word @RomainValeri is writing there**.... the guy can't be trusted :-D Just kidding!!! He knows his stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking out a remote-tracking branch directly is impossible by design in git, it fallbacks to checking out the commit that ref points to.

Seems like your local `development` branch is set to track `remote_2/development`, but you can change that.

```
# get on your branch
git checkout development

# point to the right commit
git reset --hard origin/development

# set up remote
git push -u origin HEAD
```

When you'll have to push (occasionnally) to `remote_2`, just make it explicit with `git push remote_2 HEAD`

Comment: So let's clear this up. When I execute this commads, and let's say I make some changes on development branch, when I want to push to origin, I'll just use git push, and next if I want to push the same commit to remote_2, I'll use git push remote_2 HEAD ?

Comment: If you set your branch as I suggested, yes this is the expected workflow.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, you don't actually want to checkout the remote branch directly, what you do want is to create a local branch based on a remote branch.

That's also what `git checkout` assumes you want and does, whenever you tell it to checkout a local branch that does not actually exist yet.

The command you're looking for is

```
git checkout -b development origin/development
```

(use `-B` instead of `-b` if you want to replace a pre-existing local branch called `development`)

Hint: If you want `git checkout` to always default to creating local branches based on `origin` rather than `remote_2`, add this to your `.git/config`:

```
[checkout]
    defaultRemote = origin
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout origin development

```
git checkout -b origin_developement origin/developement
```

`origin_developement` will be your local branch which tracks to `origin/developement`

Comment: Isn't the first `checkout` useless here? `HEAD` would have been reattached anyway with the `checkout -b`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @RomainValeri No need of it, I removed that command from answer.